# Unable to click on the Link Text, have tried Find_ELEMENT_BY_LINK_TEXT and quite a few other things , but its not working

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

SCREENSHOT OF THE HTML
[image]

Here is the ***screenshot of html code*** with which I am struggling , I want to click on the **Smart Watches** in the left-Nav and I am using the following code to click on it

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Smart Watches').click()
```

But I am getting the following error and I am clueless why i just cant find it on page

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link
>   text","selector":"Smart Watches"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=60.0.3112.113)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
>   6.2.9200 x86_64)

I have also tried the explicit code and Expected conditions as follows -:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
link = wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,'"Smart Watches"')))
link.click()
```

But even its giving  me **Timeout exception**

Here is the link of the page where I am stuck since morning
**https://www.kogan.com/au/shop/phones/**
 I am very new to coding , any help would be helpful !! I just want to know **why find_element_by_link_text is not working here** , it looks weird to me!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: YEs u are right

Comment: have u tried "find_element_by_partial_link_text". though does not answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `find_element_by_link_text()`, it must be an exact match to the text contained in the link. In your HTML picture, you can see "Smart Watches" but what you aren't seeing is the `SPAN` just below but still inside the `A` is closed. Most likely if you expand it, you will see additional text that you must include if you are going to use `find_element_by_link_text()`.

Another option is `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` which is more like a `contains()` instead of `equals()`. Depending on the page, it may find too many matches. You would have to try and see if it works.

Yet another option is using an XPath. There are a lot of different ways to create an XPath for this depending on exactly what you want.

This is the most general and thus most likely to find unwanted links but it may work. It's pretty much the same as `find_element_by_partial_link_text()`

```
//a[contains(.,'Smart Watches')
```

Other options include

```
//a[starts-with(.,'Smart Watches')
//li[@data-filter-facet='smart-watches']/a[contains(.,'Smart Watches')
//li[@data-filter-facet='smart-watches']/a[starts-with(.,'Smart Watches')
```

... and so on...

Comment: Thats really true , now I got why i cant locate it with link_text!!..thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it is not wotks but partial link text works. Please see my java code for the same:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.kogan.com/au/shop/phones/");

WebElement watch=driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Smart Watch"));
WebDriverWait waitElement=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(watch));
watch.click();
```

Comment: I think problem with DOM

Comment: Thanks a lot !! for ur help sankalp....but jeffC , figured it out why its not working!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way...

Accessing text: `find_element_by_xpath["//a[contains(text(), 'Smart Watches')]"].click()`

Answer (score -1):

You need to add double quotation marks, as it is in the html code:

`driver.find_element_by_link_text('"Smart Watches"').click()`

Comment: Thanks for your help , but I have tried this and even its not working :(

Answer (score -1):

most of the time it might happen that link is taking some more time to load after your page has loaded. rather than using implicit wait use explicit wait.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
link = wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"Smart Watches")))
link.click()
```

it could also be the case that link is inside another frame, in this case you will have to switch to this frame.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurang Shah . I have tried the EXPLICT WAIT also , but still getting the Timeout Exception .

Comment: @gauravtyagi then check if it's inside any frame